# String format - practice language - trace32

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

In the Trace32 language--Practice-- is there a command for formatting strings? I know of the format.hex() and format.decimal() commands but I have had no luck finding anything like a format.string()

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
FORMAT.STRING("string", 20, ' ' )
```

-> "string" to be output, 20 is the length, ' ' is fill character

Answer (score 1):

There are string functions available for Trace32. These can be found in the ide_func.pdf help document. Please find the string functions in the below link mentioned.

http://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/ide_func.pdf

Hope this will be helpful.

Thanks,
Shivakumar V W